Movie about kids who enter a race?
I remember watching this movie a long time ago when I was younger and it was about these kids who held some kind of meetings in an old shack or something. They later saved up money in a jar to enter some kind of race with go karts? I also remember they had a fishing pole, and they did something with it and a boat floating under a bridge. In the beginning, I remember a kid running from someone, I think he was in some rich persons house and stole something? I'm asking because I also remember a real distinct classical song they played in the beginning that I want to listen to again. It was also real actors, not cartoon.
I'm pretty sure this movie is a classic, so I feel pretty bad for forgetting the title :p

I think you're looking for this one The Little Rascals (1994).
Plot:

Spanky is the president of the "He-Man Woman ('woman' is misspelled as
  'womun') Haters Club" with many school-aged boys from around the
  neighborhood as members. His best friend, Alfalfa, has been chosen as
  the driver for the club's prize-winning undefeated go-kart, "The
  Blur", in the annual Soap Box Derby style race. However, when the
  announcement is made, Alfalfa is nowhere to be found.

The go-kart race is in the end.
Here's the trailer:



